# Numerically solve a set of "coupled" ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am looking for some numerical methods to solve a set of coupled ODE, coupled in the sense that
$$ \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = F\left( \alpha(t), \beta(t), \frac{d\beta}{dt}, t \right) $$
$$ \frac{d\beta}{dt} = G\left( \alpha(t), \beta(t), \frac{d\alpha}{dt}, t \right) $$
with initial conditions $\alpha(0) = \alpha_0$, $\beta(0) = \beta_0$, $\frac{d\alpha(0)}{dt} = \dot\alpha_0$, $\frac{d\beta(0)}{dt} = \dot\beta_0$.

Although these are first order ODEs, note the presence of various first derivatives in all equations that I cannot (or hoping to avoid to) decouple. Are there any numerical methods I can used to solve this?

Can methods like RK4 be used in this situation? As far as I know, it can only solve equations of the form 
$$ \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = F\left(\alpha(t), \beta(t), t\right) $$
$$ \frac{d\beta}{dt} = G\left(\alpha(t), \beta(t), t\right) $$

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you choose a given numerical method, you then need to solve a system of equations for the increment at each time step. For example, with Euler's method, you need to solve your equations for $\frac{d \alpha}{dt}$ and $\frac{d \beta}{dt}$. A crude way to do this would be to approximate the $\frac{d \alpha}{dt}$ and $\frac{d \beta}{dt}$ inside $F$ by their approximate values at the previous time. For instance an Euler type method would be $\frac{\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_k}{\Delta t}=F(\alpha_k,\beta_k,\frac{\alpha_k-\alpha_{k-1}}{\Delta t},t)$ and analogous for $\beta$.

Comment: The Matlab function ode15i should be able to deal with such systems.